# How to show and hide form using sliding effect of AnimateWindow function using c#?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using windows form for my application. I am loading another form on click of panel. Now I want to show sliding effect for opening and closing of form.I am able to add negative sliding effect while opening as form opens from right to left by overloading OnLoad event of form. But I am not able to hide the form with positive slide effect using [AnimateWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632669.aspx) function. Is there any way to do this?

This is what I have used to show the form:

```
protected override void OnLoad(System.EventArgs e)
{
  NativeMethods.AnimateWindow(this.Handle, 500, 
                  AW_ACTIVATE | AW_SLIDE | AW_HOR_NEGATIVE);

  base.OnLoad(e);    
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code you use to hide the form and describe what happens when you call it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your existing pattern - OnClosing + AW_HIDE does it in reverse.

```
protected override void OnClosing(CancelEventArgs e)
{
   AnimateWindow(this.Handle, 500, AW_ACTIVATE | AW_SLIDE | AW_HOR_NEGATIVE | AW_HIDE);

   base.OnClosing(e);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't use simply [Form.Location](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159414.aspx)  property.

Increase or decrease it's relative values to achieve sliding animation effect you want.

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://code.google.com/p/dot-net-transitions/) library might be able to do what you want.

Example code from the site, which could, in your case, be placed in the `Closing` event.

```
Transition t = new Transition(new TransitionType_EaseInEaseOut(2000));
t.add(pictureBox1, "Left", 300);
t.add(pictureBox1, "Top", 200);
t.run();
```

Once you've done the animation, you can use the `TransitionCompletedEvent` event to hide the form. (or you could animate the `Opacity` property of your form)

```
public event EventHandler<Args> TransitionCompletedEvent;
```